# pass values into ARM template parameters using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azureservicebus, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

i have a powershell script which deploys the below things

- ServiceBusNamespace
- ServiceBusQueueName
- storageAccount etc..

Now i aslo have a templatefile and **templateparameter** file which expects this values to be entered manually. i want to automate this,by automatically appending the entered values for the deployment components above to the parameters.json file.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? what doesnt work

Comment: i am getting values from user through powershell , and i want it to be applied on the "value" : " " of the parameters.json file

Comment: well that is not an explanation of what have you tried

Comment: I do not know how to try , so i asked . Please help if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the parameter name to pass in the value, like so:

```
new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment -param1 $value -templateparameter $path
```

param1 will win over the value in the parameters file. You need latest Azure Powershell for that.

Comment: "azureblob_accessKey": {
      "value": ""
    }, I have it like this in the parameter.json file , do i need to obtain this value from the powershell in a $value variable and -param1 you mentioned is the name of the value in parameter file ?

Comment: no, just pass them like so in powershell, you dont have to use parameters file at all if you dont like to